# Special chars between Android and PHP

Tags: php, android, special-characters

I need your help with this one again. I want to send special characters from an Android application to a PHP script and vice versa.

**Android Code**

---

```
...
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.mypage.com/script.php");
try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", "Español"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        InputStream inps = response.getEntity().getContent();
        InputStreamReader inp = new InputStreamReader(inps, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2"));
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(inp);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String bufferedStrChunk = null;
        while ((bufferedStrChunk = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
        }
        Result = stringBuilder.toString();
    }...
```

**PHP Code**

---

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-2");
    echo $_POST["value"];
?>
```

*First move*

I am trying to send the string "Español" from Android to PHP. I store the string into a MySQL table (UNICODE charset) and I get the string correctly. I also get the integer values of each charracter. The result is "Español" and "69.115.112.97.241.111.108". So, Android sends the character "ñ" as 241, which in the UNICODE Chart is defined as "ń". See it at http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0080

*Second move*

I return the string from PHP to Android and instead of getting "ñ" I get "ń". Here is where I am lost. When does this change and why having the same numeric value they are different? This is too much for me and I request your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you dont use UTF-8 ?

Comment: Use `base64` before you send anything  .that what i did and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ISO-8859-2** when you create the `URLEncodedEntity` that you send off. You can set this as a parameter in the constructor.

Without a specified charset, you are probably sending the data in UTF-8/UTF-16 (most common) which the server is interpreting in a different way.

**EDIT**: It looks like **ISO-8859-2** doesn't support ñ. You may have to change something server-side. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2

Comment: O.K. People. Problem solved! Thanks! I will post the solution for everybody as soon as I am allowed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

O.K.
So this is my final code, and it works. I must specify my environment: **API 15, Android 4.0.3**

*JAVA CODE*

---

```
...
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.mypage.com/script.php");
try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", "Español"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "ISO-8859-2"));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        InputStream inps = response.getEntity().getContent();
        InputStreamReader inp = new InputStreamReader(inps, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(inp);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String bufferedStrChunk = null;
        while ((bufferedStrChunk = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
        }
        Result = stringBuilder.toString();
    }
...
```

*PHP CODE*

---

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    echo utf8_encode($_POST["value"]);
?>
```

With this code I can send that string to the PHP script, store it in a database and/or return it to the Android application (and receive it just as I sent it)
I have been working on this for some days and I hope it will be of use for other Android developers. By the way, I use the Java code inside an asynchronous class, inside the doInBackground() function.

Thanks and bye